# Error loading RS jni library: UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load RSSupport: findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, android-support-library, renderscript

When using RenderScript with the support libraries I get this error on Motorola iRazr (Android 4.1.2)

```
Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load RSSupport: findLibrary returned null
```

Everything works fine on Samsung Galaxy S3.

```
        Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap);

        RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(ctx);

        ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));

        Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap);
        Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outputBitmap);

        theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
        theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
        theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);

        tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);
```

The support library jar I use is

```
build-tools/19.0.1/renderscript/lib/renderscript-v8.jar
```

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:

I copied the so files in the libs folder and verified that the so files are in the data/data/lib folder on the device.

**librsjni.so** and 
 **libRSSupport.so** exists on the device ...

EDIT:

More detailed error:

```
  02-26 16:17:42.311: D/dalvikvm(16985): Trying to load lib /data/data/de.proximity.hero/lib/libRSSupport.so    0x42616b70
  02-26 16:17:42.321: D/dalvikvm(16985): Added shared lib /data/data/de.proximity.hero/lib/libRSSupport.so 0x42616b70
  02-26 16:17:42.321: D/dalvikvm(16985): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/de.proximity.hero/lib/libRSSupport.so      0x42616b70, skipping init
  02-26 16:17:42.321: D/dalvikvm(16985): Trying to load lib /data/data/de.proximity.hero/lib/librsjni.so 0x42616b70
  02-26 16:17:42.351: E/RenderScript_jni(16985): Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1306]:   141 cannot locate '__strlen_chk'...
```

Comment: Tested on various emulators :

 4.0 arm, 4.1.2 x86 , 4.3 arm 
 all work fine with renderscript support.

Comment: can you update to build tools 19.0.2 and try again?

Comment: Same problem exists with 19.0.2 only on Motorola razr xt890 

specs : http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_razr_i_xt890-4998.php

Comment: I also added this to the project.properties file : 

   renderscript.target=19
   renderscript.support.mode=true
   sdk.buildtools=19.0.2

But i read somewhere this is not needed anymore since last ADT updates...

Comment: The error I keep getting : 

RenderScript_jni(14298): Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1306]:   140 cannot locate '__strlen_chk'...

Comment: @Tim Murray do you have any news about this or can I provide more details or tests?

Comment: looking into it right now. I think it's a particular combination of how the support library was built and the version of Android on the device, so I'm trying to break that dependency. if I get what looks like a fixed version, I'll upload it to a bug on code.google.com.

Comment: Great to hear that, cause we like the renderscript very much !

Comment: Any update on this Tim? I am still seeing the issue

Comment: @TimMurray still seeing this problem on x86 devices/emulators. Using renderscript in our gradle builds (defaultConfig { renderscriptTargetApi 19 renderscriptSupportMode true }. Any news regarding that problem.

Comment: @TimMurray This really needs a fix. Can't get it working either. Please have a look.

Comment: fix is coming in the next version of the build tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to Tim Murray](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71347) (the guy responsible for Android renderscript support) this will be fixed in the next build tools version (probably 19.1.1).

Comment: Well, now we have 20 and I still have got the same problem.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately this still isn't fixed... They forgot to incorporate this into the release. The next version should contain the correct libraries.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to use the library `build-tools/19.0.1/renderscript/lib/renderscript-v8.jar` (delete it), as google team say [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2013/09/renderscript-in-android-support-library.html), you only have to include in your `project.properties` file this lines:

```
renderscript.target=18
renderscript.support.mode=true
sdk.buildtools=19.0.3
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Does this help fix the issue described by Deacoy or is it just something that helps tidy up the setup?

Answer (score 3):

As there are no solutions at the moment we decided not to use renderscript.
Maybe with future updates if these problems get resolved.

Comment: Please, take a look to my answer, I had the same problem and finally I've fixed with these instructions.

Answer (score 3):

I know the OP does not have this problem any more, but I just want to comment on it for anyone else who bump into this. The OP in this case probably only have the libRSSupport.so for armeabi but not x86, which is why it will work on S3 but not RAZR's "i" series devices that runs on Intel chipsets.

Comment: Do you know where I can get a version that will work with devices run on Intel chipsets?

Comment: Yes, those are in a slightly different directory under x86. HOWEVER, gradle support for NDK is coming up so this won't be needed any more.

Answer (score 3):

google has fixed in [Build Tools, Revision 23.0.3](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/tools/revisions/build-tools.html) . You can find the support package in /build-tools/x.x.x/renderscript/lib.The problem has been resolved.

Comment: This fixed my issue.

Comment: Worked with 23.0.3, at last!

Comment: still causing this issue on some random devices having os version 4.x.x.

Answer (score 1):

you have to include the JNI libraries as part of your application package. Please check that you didn't accidentally strip them. You should have libRSSupport.so, librsjni.so, as well as a librs..so for each user script you have in your application. These should exist under the lib/armeabi-v7a directory for any ARM device. There should also be similar subdirectories for x86/mips.

Comment: searched all over google by more than 5hours, and entering this question more or less 10times, and I found you, in the bottom! thanks!!!

Comment: you're welcome @nyconing. Hope this answer resolves your issue