# RenderScript Support Library crashes on x86 devices

Tags: android, renderscript

I'm getting FATAL EXCEPTION running `android.support.v8.renderscript.*` on Razor i, a x86 device. The problem goes away if I use `android.renderscript.*` Also there is not problem with ARM devices. Here is the exception:

```
03-03 18:35:26.009  25011-25011/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}: android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1306]:   143 cannot locate '__strlen_chk'...
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2115)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5031)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1306]:   143 cannot locate '__strlen_chk'...
            at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:945)
            at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:982)
            at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:968)
            at com.example.app.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.createScript(MainActivity.java:92)
            at com.example.app.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:81)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5067)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5031)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: the x86 issue is a bug in our toolchain that built the libs that results in it not loading on some devices. I'm working on fixed binaries now and should have a new librsjni.so up sometime in the next day.

Comment: another thread would be good, I haven't seen any issues with Nexus S/4.2 and ColorMatrix but it's possible.

Comment: in 19.1.0 i still get this error, do you know when the bugfix will be released ?

Comment: @TimMurray I can confirm that the bug still exits in 19.1.0, my rs code runs on all ARM devieces, but not x86 Razor i... the error message is different now: android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load RSSupport: findLibrary returned null

Comment: Found related: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71347 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040821/error-loading-rs-jni-library-unsatisfiedlinkerror-couldnt-load-rssupport-fin

Answer (score 8):

I meet the same issue when I using Build Tools 21.1.1 and proguard, you may need to use the following proguard settings:

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
-keep class android.support.v8.renderscript.** { *; }
```

For more infomation: [Using the Android Renderscript v8 Support Library](http://michiganlabs.com/android-renderscript-v8-support-library/)

Comment: I think that should be accepted as answer, this worked for me

Comment: your answer doesn't make any sense, I use debug version with `minifyEnabled false`, it has nothing to do with proguard !!

Answer (score 5):

With Build Tools 21.1.1 this issue disappear.

Comment: build 29.0.3 issue exists, works only on the newest android

Answer (score 2):

I think you should also include the native libraries from \build-tools\19.0.2\renderscript\lib\packaged

Comment: I tried 19.0.3, doesn't work. In the release notes, both 19.0.2 and 19.0.3 are related to RenderScript issues. How is your experience with RenderScript so far? I found inconsistent result on difference devices...

Comment: I noticed 19.0.3 has a missing library..."android-sdk\build-tools\19.0.3\renderscript\lib\libclcore.bc" so I copyed it from the 19.0.2 and it seems to work with Andorid Studio 0.4.6. I have zero experience with renderscript, sorry, yesterday was my first renderscript day.

Comment: you shouldn't include anything, gradle adds it automatically if you have `renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true`, there are so many bad answers