# Renderscript support v8: Couldn't load RSSupport: findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, renderscript

I tested the renderscript on my devices (Nexus 4/5/S, Samsung I747). But when I release the beta to people, I collected crashes from various devices, and they're all ARM chip.

Please see the affected devices:
http://crashes.to/s/b7578ea44e5

This is the error:

```
android.support.v8.renderscript.o: Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load RSSupport: findLibrary returned null
       at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.shouldThunk()
       at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.shouldThunk()
       at com.xyang.android.timeshutter.model.imageprocessing.BaseTwoPassFilterEdgeDetector.()
       at com.xyang.android.timeshutter.model.imageprocessing.SobelEdgeDetector.()
       at com.xyang.android.timeshutter.model.BaseBitmapPersistentHelper.getBitmap()
       at com.xyang.android.timeshutter.model.BitmapPersistentHelper.cropAndSave()
       at com.xyang.android.timeshutter.model.BitmapPersistentHelper.readCompressedImageDataFromUri()
       at com.xyang.android.timeshutter.app.capture.FreeCropFragment.onClick()
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4100)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17021)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4788)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:541)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

I know there're [some bug for the Intel x86 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040821/error-loading-rs-jni-library-unsatisfiedlinkerror-couldnt-load-rssupport-fin), but why ARM devices also get this link error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you didn't include the JNI libraries as part of your application package. Please check that you didn't accidentally strip them. You should have libRSSupport.so, librsjni.so, as well as a librs..so for each user script you have in your application. These should exist under the lib/armeabi-v7a directory for any ARM device. There should also be similar subdirectories for x86/mips.

Comment: If this is the case, then how come this only happens on some of the devices? I suspect this is related to Google Play service not present. I'll check on this

Comment: The support library is not dependent on Google Play services of any kind. It likely works on the Nexus devices because they don't have to run in the actual compatibility mode, and can use actual RS on the device.

Comment: I see! What a stupid mistake, I only tested my Nexus devices mostly.

Comment: Were the libraries missing from your apk? I just want to make sure that there isn't another lurking issue here too.

Comment: I was wondering why they're missing. I specified "renderscriptSupportMode true renderscriptTargetApi 19" in my build.gradle. But they were not packed into the release and debug apk. I had to manually copy the so files from the sdk tool folder. So this is a bug?

Comment: Hi Stephen, I also found another issue. The ScriptIntrinsicColorMatrix  gives wrong result on Intel device. Can you please take a look? LinK: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73258&thanks=73258&ts=1404778637